# Color blindness test for a chart color palette

Tags: color-blindness

I have a color palette for charts. I'd like to convert it to the 3 most common types of color blindness: Protanopia (red blind), Deuteranopia (green-blind), and Tritanopia (blue-blind). And see exactly how it looks like, seen through these 3 types of users. Is there a tool for that, please?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this tool to preview your image for different types of colourblindness:

[Coblis —
Color Blindness Simulator](https://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/)

Answer (score 3):

[image][Color Oracle](https://colororacle.org/) is my preferred tool. It is great. You change the settings on the app and it changes everything in your screen.